# Why can't I see the learn option on Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I can't see the learn option in the Android Studio welcome screen. It is clearly available in the Jetbrains website tutorial.

Tutorial from the Jetbrains website:

[image: Tutorial from the Jetbrains website]

[image: Android Studio welcome screen on my pc]

Comment: Which kind of license are you using?

Comment: That button might have got lost somewhere in between `3.2.0` and `3.5.2`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not aware how to check the license. Could you please guide me how to do the same?

Comment: How do I know which version are they using?

Comment: @AmanAgarwal I am sorry, my question has no actual importance. Desktop version of AS does not provide "Learn" option

Comment: @MartinZeitler Maybe it was relocated?

Comment: The screenshot boldly states the version used, while I honestly never seen this button (or at least I never noticed it). You can use Coursera, Stepik, Udemy, etc. without that button.

Comment: My bad, I did not notice the version.Yes, I can use other online sources but wouldn't it be best to learn from the official tutorial on AS itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [EduTools](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10081-edutools/) plugin from the configure tab, after which AS will restart and the learn option will appear on the welcome screen.